# Get Button Id dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, button, twig

I need to get the button id when the button is clicked---

This is my code for my button, to show dynamically data dynamically when the condition is true.

**Twig:**

```
  {% for usr in userstats %}
    {% if usr.condition == TRUE %} 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs  myOnButton.onclick = function(event){alert(event.currentTarget.id);} myOnButton">Allow</button>
```

this is my **ajax** for my button ---

```
<script>
    $(".myOnButton").on('click', function () {
        if (confirm('{% trans %}Are you sure?{% endtrans %}')) {
            $('body').addClass('load');

            var url = '/hello/hello';
            // Submit data via AJAX
            var data = {};
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    // Redirect to view
                    url = '/hello';
                    location.href = url;
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

For being more clear- Suppose in one column we have (name:Dell, CompanyId:3001, Address- HelloDell, Phone-07555, condition:True) and in other column we have (name:Apple, CompanyId:5001, Address- HelloApple, Phone-07555, condition:True).

So how can I get the CompanyId when the button is clicked in the twig file?

Does someone know any solution for this problem?

Comment: add function with every button **<button onclick="show_companyid('3001')">Show</button>**.Here company id will change as per your rows.

Comment: @Bugfixer the problem is, id don't know what will be the company id and in my code it will show all the data which is available, so suppose when you click a button name "Dell", i need to get which button is clicked and it's id, Can you kindly give a solution for this :), thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using plain JS (without frameworks) and asuming you have multiple buttons with the class `myOnButton` you could easily do this:

```
var buttonClickHandler = function(e){
  console.log(e.target.id);
}

var buttonList = document.getElementsByClassName('myOnButton');
buttonList.forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener('click', buttonClickHandler);
});
```

EDIT1 & EDIT2:

using JQuery I assume corresponding code would look something like this:

```
$('.myOnButton').on('click', function(e){
  var buttonId = e.currentTarget.id;
  //start post request
  $.post('my/path/to/service.php', {id:buttonId}, function(data, err){
     //wait for response here
     console.log("my data yippii", JSON.stringify(data));
  })
});
```

PHP Part the `service.php` would look something like this (I have to admit it's absolutely not my strength)

```
//retrieve id
id = $_POST['id'];
```

now that you got the ID you can verify it and start to SELECT on DB or something

hope this helped

Comment: thanks for your answer, now in php how i can get that selected id, do you know that, it will solve my problem than :) thanks

Comment: I think regarding PHP questions you should open another thread. I can try to help but this would mix up the context. So just start a new question and link this as part 1 or something?

Comment: If you want ur id in php then store target.id in a js variable and then pass to php via ajax

Comment: @Bugfixer Can you kindly provide en example :)

Comment: I've tried to summarize it a little since the PHP part is pretty straightforward